# Asp.net path removed

Tags: asp.net, .net, path

I have a web site hosted on Network Solutions and it runs fine there. I'm trying to set up a test site on an old local server running Windows Server 2003. On that server the pages loaded from the menu on the site master drop on the root path. In other words the site is posted at {server}/{site name}/default.aspx. That loads. When I click on a menu to load the login page, for instance it points to {server}/login.aspx. The site name is no longer there. Both sites are .Net 4.0

Below is the CSS for the menu (the image no longer displays, as well) and the html to create the menu. What am I missing?

Greg

```
#mainNav ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
background: url(/App_Themes/Blue/Images/bg_nav.png) repeat-x left top;
float: left;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
width: 100%;    
}




      <div id="mainNav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/MemberLogin.aspx">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Register.aspx">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Resources1.aspx">Resources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Services.aspx">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/ContactNew.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Legal.aspx">Legal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/About.aspx">About</a></li>                                                                      
                </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Root/relative paths - your links above point to root (while you are expecting your root to be `site_name`..its not)

- if you want `site_name` to be app root, set it as such (virtual application) in IIS
- if you want a quick fix for the links, remove the `/` prefix so they are all in the same "relative location"...unsure if this is truly "quick" though because that means "all links"...and beware code that needs/references "root"

Comment: "if you want site_name to be app root, set it as such (virtual application) in IIS" I'll give this a try when I'm back in the office. Ideally this would work the same on both servers. Thanks.

Comment: I can't find a setting for "virtual application", but the Virtual Path is set to the site name.

Comment: @user1091524 Win2K3 - been a while for me. If memory serves: Add a `Virtual Directory`. If that's already done, set that virtual directory as an `application`. See this [for IIS6](http://www.affiliatewiz.com/support/appstartpoint.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Asp.net webforms, use of `<asp:HyperLink>` can be a solution to your problem.

```
<div id="mainNav">
            <ul>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">Home</asp:HyperLink>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/MemberLogin.aspx">Login</asp:HyperLink>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Register.aspx">Register</asp:HyperLink>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Resources1.aspx">Resources</asp:HyperLink>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Services.aspx">Services</asp:HyperLink>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink6" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/ContactNew.aspx">Contact Us</asp:HyperLink>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink7" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Legal.aspx">Legal</asp:HyperLink>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink8" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx">About</asp:HyperLink>
            </ul>
        </div>
```